# How do I pull only keys of certain types from a plist into an array?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have a plist with multiple keys in it. I am currently able to load all of the keys into an array, but I would like to only load the keys of type string into the array. Is there a way to code it so I only get the names of the keys from the plist that are of type string?

Thanks!!

Comment: b.t.w., how are you loading your plist?  are you loading it directly into a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary` or some other Objective C object?

Comment: I am using NSDictionary and loading it with contents of file from a path that is defined to point to the plist file. Then I do this to get all the keys:  NSArray *allmyKeys=[myDictionary allKeys]; So instead of all the keys being loaded, I only want the keys that are of type string. And I guess I should say only the keys whose value are of type string. But I don't want the values, just the names of the keys at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the contents of the plist and use `[obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` to pick only the strings.

```
for(id key in [mydictionary allKeys])
{
id obj = [mydictionary objectForKey:key];
   if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
   {
      [myarray addObject:key];
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you are trying to do there and I like the concept, but Xcode doesn't like the code. It returns an error of: terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 4479 thread 0xec03]
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)  - not much help in the way of figuring out why it doesn't like it. My array is an NSMutableArray, so I know it's not the issue of adding objects to it if it were just a normal array.

Comment: I also noticed that the obj is actually pulling the value for the key and not the name of the key itself, so this wouldn't work. I'm guessing that objectForKey:key is grabbing that value.

Comment: Nominally all the keys are going to be strings in a .plist . It's the objects attached to those keys which have a class. So do you want the keys which are strings (all of them) or the objects which are strings.

Comment: I want the keys. I added multiple rows to my plist file. each row has a key name - each key has a type (string, number, bool, etc...) I want all the names of the keys wherein the row is a string. So for example, I have a row where the key name is 100Series the type is string and the value is Y. I then have a row in the same plist file that is called feetBack is a type of number and has a value of 180, I don't want the name of that key - only the ones that are strings.